# Regular Expression - preg_replace - One returning space, the other returning nothing

Tags: php, regex, utf-8, preg-replace

I'm cleaning an UTF-8 string: Uppercase first letter - Remove special chars - Allow Space - Comma delimited and Numbers allowed

I Wonder, if it possible to create something more elegant than below.
The first **preg_replace** returns one Space. The **other** replaces with nothing.

```
$cleanCats = array_map(function ($element) { 
    $oneSpace = preg_replace('!\s+!', ' ', $element);
    $clean = preg_replace('~[^\pL\d ]+~u','',$oneSpace);
    return mb_strtoupper(mb_substr($clean, 0, 1)) . mb_substr($clean, 1);
}, $arrFromHtml);
echo json_encode('*' . strip_tags(implode(',', $cleanCats)) . '*');
```

The $arrFromHtml looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => B:.MÂ¤%&/W
    [1] => Î»greek
    [2] => Ð±Ð¶Ðrussian
    [3] => H<>elloj
    [4] => com,m()/a
    [5] => ÅÃ³*dÅº
    [6] => 1 spc
    [7] => 3   spc
    [8] => Ã¦Ã¸Ã¥ danish
    [9] => Euroâ¬
)
```

and this is the output:

```
*BMW,Λgreek,БжЖrussian,Helloj,Comma,Łódź,1 spc,3 spc,Æøå danish,Euro*
```

Comment: Try to remove the first `preg_replace` line and use `$clean = preg_replace('~[^\p{L}\d\s]+|(\s)+~u','$1', $element);`.

Comment: Before doing anything you have to solve the encoding problem. When you see things like `Ã¦` or `Î»` that means either that a utf8 string is not correctly displayed (when the encoding is missing in html for example) or that a string has been badly re-encoded. Once you obtain `æ` in place of `Ã¦`  and `ͻ` in place of  `Î»` you can continue your edit but not before otherwise all you will do is to loose informations.

Comment: It is the browser window that does not display the array correct. I have control over the passing of JSON data from HTML5 to PHP using always JSON/Ajax

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew
Thanks, that seams to Work nicely.
This string on my webpage:
<br>
`B:,.M¤%&/W ;λgreek;;;бжЖrussian;H<>el.loj;com,m()/a; Łó*dź ;1 spc;3   spc;æøå danish ;Euro€`

ends up like:

`BMW,Λgreek,БжЖrussian,Helloj,Comma,Łódź,1 spc,3 spc,Æøå danish,Euro`
BTW: If I want to allow a dot (.)  -  how should I change the RegEx ?

Comment: @Thorkil: ok, good news for you, in this case add `<meta charset="utf-8">` between the `<head>` tags and edit your question with the correct display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may remove the first `preg_replace` line and use

```
$clean = preg_replace('~[^\p{L}\d\s]+|(\s)+~u','$1', $element);
```

It will find all occurrences of

- `[^\p{L}\d\s]+` - 1+ chars other than Unicode letters, digits or whitespace
- `|` - or
- `(\s)+` - 1 or more whitespaces, the last one captured into Group 1.

The replacement is `$1`, that is, the last whitespace captured into Group 1 (hence, all but the last whitespace are removed).

To also allow `.` in the string, just add it to the negated character class:

```
$clean = preg_replace('~[^\p{L}\d\s.]+|(\s)+~u','$1', $element);
```